# Not able to get jQuery DataTable to work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm trying to get DataTables to work for the first time. I'm following the example off of their site but I'm not getting it to work. I'm hoping I'm just missing something simple.

Below is the code. In the JavaScript I'm able to get the alert to show so I know my button is tied to the click event but after that nothing happens. Looking at the developer's tools I don't see any errors.

I initially tried the CDN but then loaded DataTables through NuGet and used local references for the .js and .css files. Still no go.

I put a break point on the server side of the controller to see if it would get to that point and it never it's that breakpoint. So, I don't know if that's because the URL is not pointing to the correct spot or if I will never get to the break point because the DataTables is client side?

```
<link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@section scripts {

    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").bind("click", function () {

                alert("here");

               $('#tblTransaction').DataTable({
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/Admin/LoadTestData",
                        "type": "GET",
                        "datatype": "json"
                    },
                    "columns": [
                            { "data": "emp_lastname", "autoWidth": true }
                    ]
                });
            })
        });

    </script>
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult LoadTestData()
{
    using (var ctx = new VTContext())
    {
        var data = DAL.GetMultipleEmployees("291289","9/19/2017"); 
        return Json(new { data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the link to the tutorial that you're following?

Comment: http://demo.dotnetawesome.com/implement-jquery-datatable-in-aspnet-mvc

Comment: You can check that the datatables js and css fileds have loaded by looking in the Network pane of the developer tools.  You will also be able to see the datatables ajax request in the dev tools, although I would have expected to to see `'serverSide: 'true'` in the datatables init code for this to work...